# How to retain Enigmail/OpenPGP passphrase with Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, thunderbird, openpgp, enigmail, kwallet

I am using Enigmail with Thunderbird to crypt my emails and I would like it to retain my passphrase for some time. In Enigmail settings it is possible to set a duration to memorize the passphrase. However I get the following message:

> Your system uses a specialized tool for passphrase handling such as gnome-keyring or seahorse-agent. Unfortunately OpenPGP cannot control the passphrase timeout for the tool you are using. therefore the respective timeout settings in OpenPGP are disregarded.

How to get rid of it and stop typing the passphrase hundreds of times? I am running Kubuntu and didn't find any option for this in the Kwallet.

Comment: Still having this issue ?

Comment: It seems to work now. I think the new version of Thunderbird (45.2.0) solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can say as a beginner is that you will need to get this in line. Keys are about security and you should have control of the tools for such objective.

As of MAN :

[image: contextalws]

Answer (score -1):

In `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf` try to comment out the line `use-agent` and kill the running agent / restart.

Comment: In `~/.gnupg` I have no `gpg.conf` file. There is only `gpg-agent.conf` which contain two lines:     `default-cache-ttl 300` and `max-cache-ttl 999999`